# Prevent multiple bean instantiation on inheritance

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following problem I'm trying to overcome:

I have a Spring base component:

```
@Service
public class Circle {
...
  @Autowired
  public Circle() {
     loadFromDB();
  }
...
}
```

I have another component which inherits it:

```
@Service
public class BlueCircle extends Circle {
...
}
```

The problem here is `loadFromDB` is called twice because Spring instantiate `Circle` two times: first time when it "discovers" class `Circle` and a second time because of the inheritance.

Is there a "Spring" way to avoid this?

Comment: No, neither there is a java way. The problem is you are calilng this from the constructor and in the hierarchy the super constructor is also called. So to fix you shouldn't do this in the constructor but somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a service extending another service is never a good approach. I would rather suggest you to create a service interface and then make your two services implementing that interface. In this way you should not have anymore this problem because you would call *loadFromDB()* only in one of your service.

Comment: It won't help me because I need one service to extend the other so it can override some of the base class functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need instance of BlueCircle then you might have to remove @Service on Circle class.

Comment: My app creates instance of both `Circle` and `BlueCircle` --> `Circle` cannot be abstract.

Comment: Are you expecting something like this  -                                                          
         @Bean                                                                                 
          public BlueCircle blueCircle(){                                 
           return new BlueCircle ();       ​}                                                                                   
         ​@Bean                                                                                 
          ​public Circle circle(BlueCircle b){    return b;}